# Наследование собственной темы для другого уровня API в android?

Tags: android-sdk, android

**Дано:**

Собственная тема, наследующая одну из стандартных, переопределяющая некоторые атрибуты и определяющая свои. Назначена темой приложения в манифесте.

**Задача:**

Создать тему для другого **API** так, чтобы она содержала все свойства имеющейся темы и переопределяла свои атрибуты (например тема для **API>21**, с атрибутом `android:navigationBarColor`), которые нельзя указать в темах для меньшего уровня **API**.

**Возможное решение:**

1. Банально скопировать определение темы в файл `values-API_LEVEL/styles.xml` и добавить нужные атрибуты. Смущает нужда править множество файлов при изменении общих для всех **API** атрибутов.
2. Переопределить свою тему в теме с другим названием и назначать её программно. Тоже вариант, но не хочется городить лишний код.

**Вопрос:**

Как таки и можно ли в `values-API_LEVEL/styles.xml` как-то переопределить тему так, чтобы она имела название идентичное названию темы из `values/styles.xml`, наследовала все свойства этой темы и определяла новые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем так:

1. Создаём в `values/styles.xml` общую тему от которой потом будем наследоваться

   ```
   <style name="Base.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
       <!--определяем здесь атрибуты общие для всех API-->
   </style>

   <style name="MyTheme" parent="Base.MyTheme" >
       <!--тут ничего писать не надо, всё уже сделано выше-->
   </style>
   ```
2. В `values-v21/styles.xml` создаём тему с тем же именем и тем же родителем, наследуем таким образом все её свойства и добавляем новые

   ```
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="Base.MyTheme">
       <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/material_grey_500</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. В манифесте указываем приложению тему MyTheme:

   ```
   android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
   ```

Comment: при всём уважении - я пользуюсь средой разработки eclipce, так вот именно то что вы написали  он автоматически делает при создании нового проекта. Могут только варьироваться папки *values* для версий sdk

Comment: Гм, действительно...Толи меня AndroidStudio запутала, то ли я сам себя запутал...=)